# how to delete files from remote server using phpStorm

Tags: php, ssh, phpstorm

So I've added remote server to phpStrom and I can change files there.
But if I delete files they disappear only from my computer not on the server.
How to delete files from remote server using phpStorm?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To **manually** delete files from remote location -- use **Remote Host tool window** (or `Tools | Deployment | Browse Remote Host` if it's not visible) -- navigate and delete any file(s) you want.

For keeping your remote host in sync with local (i.e. to delete remote file as soon as local gets deleted as well) you need to enable automatic upload in `Settings | Deployment | Options`, in particular:

1. Upload changed items automatically to the  default server
2. **Delete target items when source ones do not exist**

[image]

Obviously, you need to configure all those options as most suitable to your workflow.