# How to delete remote branch on phpstorm after I delete on gitlab?

Tags: phpstorm, gitlab

How to delete remote branch on phpstorm after I delete on gitlab

After deleting that branch on GitLab, I cannot select the same branch in my PhpStorm-managed local repo without seeing the error message:

```
Failed to delete remote branch origin/branch1

unable to delete 'branch1': remote ref does not exist failed to push
some refs to 'http://user@gitlab.company.com/owner/projectname.git'
```

How can I avoid that error message?

Comment: [how to delete files from remote server using phpStorm][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22091527/4506589

just follow answer and git fetch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is seen when a remote repo has no longer a specific branch, but an IntelliJ GUI like PhpStorm still reference it as a remote tracking branch.
[See IDEA-96402](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96402) (Dec. 2012, not yet closed):

> Remote branches on a project hosted on bitbucket.org don't exist anymore, but are still listed on my phpstorm installation.
>
> 1. Bitbucket does not list the branch anymore
> 2. When I select the branch to delete from within PHPSTORM, i receive the message

```
Failed to delete remote branch origin/hotfix/bug-121: null: NON_EXISTING
```

The workaround is for now a manual one:

> 1. You can call `git remote prune origin` in the command line.
> 2. If you call `Update Project` to pull from the remote, it will automatically prune all obsolete references.

The ticket adds:

> Note that if you delete a remote branch from the IDE or from the command line, the reference is deleted as well.
>   This request is about deleting remote reference on the branch which was removed from the remote via some other way, not from this repository.